# React Scroll Spy Library (organism-react-scroll-nav) npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

Have anyone worked with React Scroll Spy Library (organism-react-scroll-nav)[organism-react-scroll-nav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/organism-react-scroll-nav)

How to use ScrollReceiver, scrollDispatch? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Jony, you can use 'react scrollspy nav' instead of the above package. It has minimal setup with limited features. You can make your Navbar fully customized.

**LINK:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollspy-nav

**Working Example:** http://learningdemo.galaxyweblinks.com/alok-mali/react-demo/react-bootstrap/

My Code

```
<ScrollspyNav
    scrollTargetIds={[
      "home-section",
      "about-section",
      "services-section",
      "portfolio-section",
      "pricing-section",
      "contact-section"
    ]}
    activeNavClass="active"
  >
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" fixed="top">
      <Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="#home-section">HOME</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#about-section">ABOUT</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#services-section">SERVICES</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#portfolio-section">PORTFOLIO</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing-section">PRICING</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#contact-section">CONTACT</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </ScrollspyNav>
```

Where home-section, about-section, etc are the ids of my sections.